# Optimise wordpress database using SQL after deleting registered images from Media Folder

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, images, database, media-library

I have used **Media Cleaner Pro** Plugin to clean few batches of registered images. Additionally i have updated my functions.php so these unused images will not be generated in future.

```
function wpse_unset_images( $sizes ){
unset( $sizes[ 'medium_large' ] );
unset( $sizes[ 'large' ]);
unset( $sizes[ 'member-two' ] );
unset( $sizes[ 'member' ] );
unset( $sizes[ 'shop_thumbnail' ]);
unset( $sizes[ 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail' ] );
unset( $sizes[ 'widget-thumb-medium' ] );
return $sizes; 
}
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'wpse_unset_images' );
```

I can clearly see the visible difference in my web space which has reduced from 7GB to 4GB and also indoes has come down to half from almost 300,000 to 1,70,000.

But i have seen that there is no difference in DB size. It means plugin has **NOT** removed required rows/data from database. Database size is still 350MB.

I have around 12K products, but having almost

- 700,000 rows in **wp_postmeta**
- 40K rows in **wp_posts**

**I need some guidance to clean/optimize database using SQL to remove data related to removed images.**

NOTE* - Additional rows in DB may also be due to fact that i updated product prices in BULK for almost 12K products twice. I need to clear that mess also.

Comment: I don't think image sizes have separate database rows, so removing image sizes will only remove the per-size metadata for each image, not any actual rows.

Comment: 12,000 products is a lot, and they have a lot of metadata, so the number of post and meta rows doesn't seem unusual. What problem are you trying to solve here? If you're having performance problems then just randomly trying to reduce available image sizes and database rows is almost certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - Yes you are right... im having performance issue only whenever i edit my products, CPU spikes to 60%.... Otherwise my wp-admin, front end is just exceptionally working fine....